# Is there a way to use pygtex files without rerunning pygmentize?

Tags: minted, pygments

I have written a document describing a Python module and used `minted` with `pygmentize`. I have now hit an unexpected roadblock, as I need to hand control of the document to my company's publishing department for final formatting. That department has LaTeX but not Python and so I do not think they can install `pygmentize`, which requires Python.

Before abandoning `minted` and formatting a different way, I'm wondering if there's a way I can prepare the document so that they can compile it (assuming no changes to the code).

For example, if I had a `.pygtex` file for an inline compilation that said something like `\mintedinline{python}|hello_world|`:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{n}{hello\PYGZus{}world}
\end{Verbatim}
```

Is there a way to put that into my document instead?

What about something like,

```
\begin{minted}{python}
print(p.__dict__())
#{
# 'lat': 90.0,
# 'lon': 0.0
}
\end{minted}
```

which creates the file

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{n+nb}{print}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{n}{p}\PYG{o}{.}\PYG{n+nv+vm}{\PYGZus{}\PYGZus{}dict\PYGZus{}\PYGZus{}}\PYG{p}{())}
\PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{}\PYGZob{}}
\PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{} \PYGZsq{}lat\PYGZsq{}: 90.0,}
\PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{} \PYGZsq{}lon\PYGZsq{}: 0.0}
\PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{}\PYGZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

I believe that the list as ordered in the `.aux` file gives the order that they are used in the document (some are used more than once), so I could identify the`.pygtex` file that needs to be used at each location, but I can't figure out how to insert and compile the information.

Comment: minted has an option specifically to re-use the existing cached files so not requiring python (or shell escape) it was added after a similar question on this site.

Comment: Oh, I didn't find the question in my search, I will see if I can find it and read the docs more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: look for `frozencache`option

Comment: see https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/113#issuecomment-223451550

Comment: It does, thank you. I was searching the documents to understand the hashing thinking that was the answer. I don't have the credentials to label this as a duplicate question but now see that it is.

Comment: it's always easier to search when you are looking for one of your own answers:-)